# Is it possible to choose to select from which database in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, select, hive, hiveql

I have one table but in two different databases. How can I query to based on some flag to select only from one of them?

For example:

```
   insert into db2.table2
   select * from db1.table1 if flag is true else select * from db2.table
```

What's the corresponding query (that works) to this sudo query?

Comment: The flag is should be calculated through bit-wise AND of two boolean flags.

Comment: HiveQL is not a procedure language. Use shell/python/Java, etc. Also have a look at this: http://www.hplsql.org/doc

Comment: The solution that I found is using IF THEN in hive; In the IF statement I can check the flag which is set through some config/property at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass database parameter using shell

```
#!/bin/bash

#calculate database as you want here
db=db1

#substitute variable and execute
hive -e "insert into db2.table2
   select * from $db.table1"
```

You can do similar in Hive using UNION ALL, though it is not efficient way:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE OUTPUT_TABLE                                                                                                                                      
 SELECT * FROM DB1.TABLE1 WHERE (${FLAG_one} = TRUE) --any boolean condition
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM DB2.TABLE1 WHERE  (${FLAG_one} = FALSE) --any boolean condition
```

Comment: I want to have such flexibility inside the hive query itself and then from outside I set a flag to decide to choose from which db.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INPUT_DATABASE = db1
 IF FLAG_one = TRUE and FLAG_two = FALSE THEN  INPUT_DATABASE = db2                                                                                                                                       
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE {OUTPUT_DATABASE}.{TABLE_ONE}                                                                                                                                      
 SELECT * FROM {INPUT_DATABASE}.{TABLE_TWO}
```

Comment: is it hpl/sql or what?

Comment: INPUT_DATABASE, OUTPUT_DATABASE, FLAG_one, and FLAG_two are all in properties file. Can't we use IF THEN or CASE statement? https://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/conditional-functions-in-hive.html

Comment: This will not work in Hive. Conditional function can be used in the select, not like you posted unfortunately. HiveQL is not a procedural language

Comment: I see. I will rewrite it in a way that the conditional statement is in the select?

Comment: Now I understand what you want. Use UNION ALL + WHERE condition (it can be your flags checking) like in my answer

Comment: I like this idea, however the code expands by double.

Comment: yes. this is why i said it is not efficient. but there is no other way in hive because it cannot calculate variables like in your code. variables in hive work as text substitution w/o calculation. you can calculate variables outside and substitute in single statement like in my first example w shell. pass already calculated db, table name. etc

Comment: look: if you are passing flag1 and flag2, why cannot you just pass db instead?

Comment: Because this calculation must be done for each query. It seems it is not possible to do so, unless doubling the whole code, which is very inefficient especially for complicated queries where there are nested joins and stuff. Still need to think how to make it efficient, the union all will work but it makes the queries very complicated. I was looking for to have the flexibility to select between two dbs even in nested complicated queries

Comment: sorry. I still do not understand your last argumentation. why cant you calculate DB outside, how flags are connected w query and why you can't calculate DB outside hive? You sait flags are in properties. Some process have to read properties and calculate DB, whatever else and pass it as parameters

Comment: simple truth about hive: database cannot be calculated in a query. it should be known before execution, also variables are not calculated before substitution, also procedure logic is not supported.

Comment: I can use the database outside in property. My concern is that the queries become more complicated if since for each select i have to do union all. So the idea is always to be able to select between two databases. Using union all solution the queries become more complicated. imagine there queries already are nested selections, joins, union all, and blah blah... However, it seems I don't have other options

Comment: you do not need union if you calculate variable outside hive. pass as many calculated variables in hive session as necessary. for example different db variables for each query: db1, db2 or the same one for every query in a session.

Comment: I think using the union all and condition for the least level selection even in complicated queries will work. So basically each selection from a db.tb can be done through union all where db is either db1 or db2 (not both) using the condition (flags which are set from outside). Thanks!